# Bootstrap - Android display too small

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, viewport, smartphone

Using bootstrap 3.3.6.css and jquery-1.11.3.min.js.

Been working on a site and routinely testing it on everything once enough changes have been made.  I got a little behind on testing the Galaxy S4 display so did it today only to find that the site is about 1/3-1/2 the size it should be.

So, I started with a blank index.html and gradually added everything in, section by section.  During all this, the display looked fine, however, I did notice that at some point, the display would start out small but eventually expanded to the correct size and perfectly filled the display.

I am at a total loss on this one.  The view-port meta tag is correct as far as I know:

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This is the site, if you would like to see it yourself:  http://www.motospec.parishpc.com

Has anyone experienced this before?
Can anyone suggest a possible fix?

Comment: are you referring on the map?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, through trail and error - systematically commenting suspect code out.

The problem turned out to be an iframe for a google map:

Oddly enough, this worked without problem for a while. Have no idea why it all of a sudden it started to cause and issue.

Other fact:  at the top of the screen for the smartphone view is the company logo that is actually a link to index.html.  The page would display in the smaller scale, and by pressing the 'home' link, so to speak, the page would redraw and the scale would then be correct.

Go figure.

2 rules to development:

rule 1) coding is voodoo at times
rule 2) can't change rule 1

Thanks for looking...

Comment: I looked at it.. It was really strange